# How to deduce the template argument when storing a lambda-templated class as a member of another class?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I have a question about storing a lambda-templated object as a class member. The `Invoker` class is a templated class storing an arbitrary lambda function. I want to store an instance of an `Invoker` in another class, `Worker`. However, I do not know how to fill the template argument `TCallback` when the `Invoker` is used as a class member. It does not deduce like the first line in the `main` function. As shown in the comments, I am trying to define a lambda somewhere in `Worker` and pass it to its member of the type `Invoker`.

What I have tried is to use `decltype` of a class method but it could not be invoked like a generic lambda - it needs the class object context to run.

Much appreciated for any ideas and maybe some workarounds.

Thank you.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename TCallback>
struct Invoker {
  explicit Invoker(TCallback&& cb) : cb(cb) {}

  TCallback cb;

  void invoke() {
    cb();
  }
};

struct Worker {
  void some_callback() {
    std::cout << "callback in worker\n";
  }

  // Not working: some_callback is a member function and can only be called with the context object
  Invoker<decltype(&Worker::some_callback)> invoker{&Worker::some_callback};

  // How to make a something like this?
//   auto lambda_in_class = [&]{some_callback()};
  // Invoker<decltype(lambda_in_class)> invoker{lambda_in_class};
};

int main() {
  Invoker invoker([]{std::cout << "invoker\n";});
  Worker worker;
  worker.invoker.invoke();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to use remplates? This works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Invoker {
  explicit Invoker(std::function<void()> cb) : cb(cb) {}

  std::function<void()> cb;

  void invoke() {
    cb();
  }
};

struct Worker {
  void some_callback() {
    std::cout << "callback in worker\n";
  }

   // Not working: some_callback is a member function and can only be called with the context object
   Invoker invoker{std::bind(&Worker::some_callback, this)};

   // How to make a something like this?
   std::function<void()> lambda_in_class = [&]{some_callback();};
   Invoker invoker1{lambda_in_class};
};

int main() {
  Invoker invoker([]{std::cout << "invoker\n";});
  Worker worker;
  worker.invoker.invoke();
  worker.invoker1.invoke();
  return 0;
}
```

---

You can do it with templates as well, but you will need template deduction guide (which is C++17 feature) for lambdas:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename TCallback>
struct Invoker {
  explicit Invoker(TCallback cb) : cb(cb) {}

  TCallback cb;

  void invoke() {
    cb();
  }
};

template<typename T>
Invoker(T) -> Invoker<T>;

struct Worker {
  void some_callback() {
    std::cout << "callback in worker\n";
  }

  // Not working: some_callback is a member function and can only be called with the context object
  Invoker<decltype(std::bind(&Worker::some_callback, static_cast<Worker *>(0)))> invoker{std::bind(&Worker::some_callback, this)};

  // How to make a something like this?
//   auto lambda_in_class = [&]{some_callback()};
  // Invoker<decltype(lambda_in_class)> invoker{lambda_in_class};
};

int main() {
  Invoker invoker([]{std::cout << "invoker\n";});
  Worker worker;
  worker.invoker.invoke();
  return 0;
}
```

Lambda inside class will only work with `std::function`, since it is impossible to use `auto` for class member and you can't define its type any other way.

For member functions, to simplify its usage you even can create special constructor and deduction guide. Like this:

```
  // Add constructor to Invoker definition
  template<typename T>
  Invoker(void (T::*func)(), T* obj) : cb(std::bind(func, obj)) {}

// Add template guide after Invoker definition
template<typename T>
Invoker(void (T::*func)(), T* obj) -> Invoker<decltype(std::bind(func, obj))>;


  // Now you can declare invoker in Worker like this
  decltype(Invoker(&Worker::some_callback, static_cast<Worker *>(0))) invoker{&Worker::some_callback, this};

  // Or outside, like this
  Worker worker;
  auto invoker = Invoker{&Worker::some_callback, &worker};
```

Comment: Thanks! using `std::function` is definitely doable but I would also like to learn how to deal with this situation when type deduction cannot work for the class member.

Comment: @YuanyiWu Added some variations...

Comment: Excellent example! Two questions: 1. the code did not compile in Visual Studio due to C2665; 2. I am unfamiliar with the deduction guide. It seems if I remove the deduction guide `template<typename T> Invoker(T) -> Invoker<T>;`, it still compile and run. Is it required here?

Comment: Another off-topic question: it seems the compiler is capable to deduce the type specifications. Any idea why this feature is not enabled for class members and we have to write so many boilerplate codes?

Comment: 1. Something weird happening with MSVC, for some reason it have `const` `this` when initializing `invoker`. So you either can add cast `const_cast<Worker *>(this)` or use second deduction guide. 2. This deduction guide was for out-of-class lambda. It didn't work without.

Comment: *Any idea why this feature is not enabled?* I have no idea, but if I have to guess probably so as to not deduce wrong type from default value...

Answer (score 1):

The problem with:

```cpp
Invoker<decltype(&Worker::some_callback)> invoker{&Worker::some_callback};
```

is that `some_callback` is a non-static member function. When you call it, an implicit `this` pointer is actually passed to it. So when you call it through the member function pointer, an object of `Worker` is required(which does not exist in your `Invoker` class.

---

One workaround is to use a bind expression to bind a `this` pointer with the `some_callback`:

```cpp
std::bind(&Worker::some_callback, this)
```

And the result type can then be converted to a `std::function<void()>` and stored in `Worker.invoker`:

```cpp
Invoker<std::function<void()>> invoker{std::bind(&Worker::some_callback, this)};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Wr5ebezzb)

---

Another solution is to use a static member function instead. By using a static function, you would not need to pass a `this` pointer anymore, and you can initialize `invoker` directly with `&Worker::some_callback`:

```cpp
Invoker<std::function<void()>> invoker{&Worker::some_callback};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/W35bd4WGY)

Comment: Thank you! Binding the member function to the invoker's template was just one of my attempt. My goal is to bind an arbitrary lambda to the Invoker's template as well as storing the Invoker as a member (not using std::function). Do you think this is possible?

Comment: @YuanyiWu Only a single type can be bonded to `invoker` since the exact type of `invoker` can not change. To bind multiple types, the best way is to make `Worker` a template class.

Comment: @YuanyiWu Also note that based on your `Invoker`, `cb` can't take any arguments, and any return values are discarded, so any functions passed to it are effectively `void()` type.

Comment: Yes. The callback is conceptual so it's signature doesn't really matter here. After all, the actual type of a lambda is private to the compiler.

Comment: For the suggestion of making the Worker class a template, I actually do not want to bind multiple times to the callback. I only want to store the callback once (on initialization, maybe in the constructor). The issue is that the Invoker's template type is not deductible.

Comment: I am expecting some pseudo-code like the commented-out lambda declaration in the code example. It looks straightforward but seems very impossible to achieve.

Comment: @YuanyiWu The problem with your commented code isn't that `invoker`'s type can not be deduce, it's because that `lambda_in_class` does not have a type. Member default value does not provide type information to the member itself. It only provides information on how they are being initialized.

Comment: @YuanyiWu Instead of `auto lambda_in_class = ...`, you must manually give it a concrete type, like `function<void()>`. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hsMbbMhsE)